# How to view all mounted devices and respective free space

Tags: nautilus, disk-usage

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and I don't see **My Computer** option in Nautilus. I want this option so that I can view the disk statistics.

Is there any other way to list all mounted devices and their respective free spaces within Nautilus? Because I find it very hard to go to properties every time or use a disk analyser which takes loads of time or a screenlet which takes up memory. Is there any other simple solution?

Comment: Conky takes up almost zero memory, and it can do what you ask for and more. Might want to take a look into that. Just an added tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of 11.10, but atleast in 12.04, you can enable your Status bar in Nautilus which will give the free space in your current Partition.

Although this does not list all file systems at once, it is pretty handy to know the free space in the current file system.

To enable Status Bar in Nautilus, just type the following in BASH.
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar true`

If at some point, you want to remove your Status Bar (which I would find very hard to believe), you can do so by using the following command.
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar false`

Or, if you are more of a GUI kind of guy, install dconf-editor and go to
`org > gnome > nautilus > window state`
and select start-with-status-bar.

Hope that helped.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the solution. This is awesome. Works for me in 11.10

Answer (score 4):

Use `df` in terminal. Learning bash will save you insurmountable amounts of time, check out a guide.

Comment: That does the job. But is there any simple GUI program for that? Which displays a bar like in Windows 7

Comment: While there may be one, you're defeating the very purpose of using Linux/Unix. If you want it to be like Windows then why bother with Ubuntu?

There's a lot of power in BASH, take the time to learn it and it will pay off immensely.

Comment: I love ubuntu and the freedom in linux environment when compared to windows. And that is why I am using ubuntu. But when I need to free up some space in my hard disk or when I need to know the disk space usage, I don't have any option in nautilus, which is disappointing.

Comment: Try baobab. I think it does the job.

Comment: `df -h` is easier to read

Answer (score 3):

This isn't within Nautilus, but...

Load the System Monitor (press the Super key, and type System Monitor in the dash). Then go to the File Systems tab.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use diskusage analyser to see what is being used on your computer.

You can also use disk utility to see all devices

Comment: I am aware of both the utilities, but they are not as simple as listing the devices and their free spaces in nautilus. Disk Usage analyser takes loads of time and does not refresh on its own.